# Can't install apps as /var/cache/apt/archives/ is full

Tags: apt, partitioning, gparted

Thanks in advance for any help!

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS. Initially when I set it up - the guide I used told me that 16GB should be enough for my root partition. Turns out not so... I've used 96% and can no longer install apps or app updates.

I was told to use GParted Live USB to resize my root partition. To initialise the bootable USB, I need to install 'mtools'... which I can't do because root has run out of space... (sigh)

I get the following message when running `apt install mtools`:

> E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

I don't have access to another machine. I've tried `apt clean`, `apt autoclean`, `apt autoremove` - but the error persists.

**Questions**

- How can I install mtools?
- Is there anything else I can remove from root to get back a little bit of space, so I can install mtools and ultimately resize the partition?

Output of `df -h /var/cache/apt/archives/`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2   15G   15G     0 100% /
```

Output of `du -h /var/cache/apt/archives/`:

```
4.0K    /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
60K     /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Comment: You could "initialize" the bootable USB using a different machine. What you can remove depends upon what you have installed, whether your data is backed up, and how you handle your logfiles.

Comment: Thanks @user535733. I looked into clearing logs - and ended up using **journalctl --vacuum-size** to reduce the journal size by ~100MB. While it freed up space in root, it didn't help to overcome the initial **/var/cache/apt/archives/** error. Do you know why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough memory, you can use tmpfs to allocate temporary space on that folder from your memory:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=500Mi,mode=1777 tempspace /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

You might need to delete contents of that folder in order to mount

But I don't think this will solve your problem. Since it's only a folder to save the .deb files. Installation will copy files to other folders.

Do you really need mtools? Maybe you can use some other disk image burning program, I remember Etcher, it was portable. You can change the folder name on above command to /mnt , download Etcher and ISO file there (make sure to adjust size accordingly) to make a bootable USB.

Maybe you can free some space by running `sudo apt autoremove` or by clearing /var/log/

note: do not delete the log files/folders but truncate them only! otherwise some services will not start. find the big files and do `> filename` in terminal

Comment: Thanks @Cagri for the suggestions. I looked into clearing logs - and ended up using **journalctl --vacuum-size** to reduce the journal size by ~100MB. While it freed up space in root, it didn't help to overcome the initial **/var/cache/apt/archives/** error. Do you know why that might be?

I've tried **autoremove**, and I'm unable to download Etcher as I run into the same problem. I'll look into the **tmpfs** mount suggestion :)

Comment: after clearing them, did you reboot? you might need to reboot for apps to actually release the free space

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied - really appreciate the help.

Turns out that clearing space from root *was* the answer - it was just that the ~100MB I'd cleared from `/var/log/journal` wasn't enough.

I vacuumed another ~200MB, the error disappeared, I was able to create a GParted Live USB and gave some extra space to my root partition. All is now humming nicely...